# Is nepotism a bad thing?

Tags: nepotism

Question inspired by a news article - that one company hired another company (and did not disclose the relation) - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38130398

> These decisions follow reports of an arrangement between Sports Direct and Barlin Delivery Limited which was **not disclosed as a related party** in the company's financial statements

#### Nepotism

> the practice among those with power or influence of favouring relatives or friends, especially by giving them jobs.

One could see upsides such as **trust**, **loyalty** and prior knowledge of an individual.

Wikipedia has some views on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepotism#In_employment

> Arguments are made both for and against employment granted due to a family connection, which is most common in small, family run businesses. On one hand, nepotism can provide stability and continuity. Critics cite studies that demonstrate decreased morale and commitment from non-related employees.

**Is nepotism a bad thing?**

I can admit it makes things sensitive and complicated - enough to read some of the questions tagged with "nepotism" - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepotism

I am still a little bit unsure whether nepotism is inherintly a bad thing and what are the way to make it work.

Comment: @dan1111 I disagree. While our bread and butter is in advice on dealing with real situations, we have scores of great questions that ask about general ethics and professionalism. While I'm having a hard time entertaining the notion that nepotism could be a positive anywhere outside organized crime, the question itself seems perfectly on topic.

Comment: What we *should* avoid is turning this into a discussion, which means no answering the question in the comments @Pete :)

Comment: @Lilienthal fair enough, maybe the abstract nature of it is ok, but I have a hard time seeing how this will generate anything other than a broad, opinion-based discussion.

Comment: @dan1111 It seems clearly answerable to me. Answers should focus on defining on the degrees of nepotism (foot in the door versus preferential treatment) and the pros and cons involved with such an arrangement. The answer below is an excellent example of how even subjective topics can be answered by falling back on sources that can speak with some authority. OP isn't asking if we think it's bad, but why it is or can be considered bad which is in line with other questions that ask "Is it professional to do X?" or "Is Y a bad practice?". **Vote to reopen**, though it could use further edits.

Comment: There is plenty of positives about nepotism, and plenty of negatives. Some of the positives are also negatives dependent on the perspective of the person looking at them.

Comment: In my opinion, nepotism is a great thing, as long as it's my relatives and friends, and not yours. I can't imagine a good answer to this question that isn't just opinion.

Comment: If nepotism promotes friends, then people with good social skills *(making friends easily)* would be promoted. People with good social skills are great asset to any company - technical skills can be easily learnt, to change personality is much more difficult. One of many potential arguments, not an expert here.

Comment: @MichalStefanow, then you exclude introverts who are often better at their jobs than extroverts. Some social skills are necessary but the degree they are necessary depends a great deal on the jobs and, no, not all technical skills are easily obtained.  I have seen way more incompetents hired from nepotism than any other factor. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Any system of dividing responsibility that does not do so by an estimation of merit alone will by definition give less optimal results. Besides, always choosing from a group of people that are like-minded means that opportunities for necessary pivoting and step change are most likely missed.

Family businesses usually go out of business after 3 generations [as Forbes says](http://www.forbes.com/sites/aileron/2013/07/31/the-facts-of-family-business/#106c630946e7):

> Less than one third of family businesses survive the transition from first to second generation ownership. Another 50% don’t survive the transition from second to third generation.

If you compare businesses that survived their startup phase those that are not family owned businesses perform better. There is [a podcast about it by freakonomics](http://freakonomics.com/2011/08/05/if-handing-off-a-family-business-to-the-next-generation-whats-the-key-thing-to-avoid/) that explores this topic. In short, if family businesses were to not elect CEOs that were not completely uneducated (i.e not attending top universities, not being well enough groomed for the position), the statistical significance of the difference is non-existent. But, since that is the extreme end of nepotism, I believe the argument still holds. **Nepotism is bad for business.**

Comment: Interesting naswer Stian, thanks for contributing and including some sources. I've taken the liberty of copyediting your post. I'd only suggest rephrasing "necessary pivoting and step change" to something that's not as heavy on the buzzwords.

Comment: this looks more like hand-waving pushing the problem to "estimation of merit" assuming it's simple (and it isn't)

Comment: The rate of failure of all businesses is quite high, so the first piece of information is fairly meaningless without an appropriate comparison to non-family businesses.  The study mentioned in the podcast does attempt to make a comparison, but I wonder about the strength of the evidence.  Leadership transitions in family-owned and non-family-owned businesses are likely to occur and different frequency and for different reasons, and these reasons may have an impact on the results.

Comment: Na... this might apply in some places, mostly capitalist I would think, and not even all of those and not in all industries in any of them and there is a host of factors which make nepotism viable in many instances at many levels in business. Leveraging personal networks at high levels is a large part of getting big contracts, in fact the more money you're talking about the more attractive nepotism can be.

Comment: @Lilienthal Erm, your edits made it way better. I thought I was fluent. Thank you for your suggestions. As for "pivoting" and "step change" - they are quite well defined. But I guess "change rapidly in answer to customers desires" will do?

Comment: @dan1111 Yes, it is fairly meaningless without, but you should listen through the podcast, they are fairly rigorous with their statistics. I am sorry for not writing a summary report and serving you on that silver plate there, sir... ;-) They have a comparison against fortune 500 companies and a in depth study of the Heinz company IIRC. All quite interesting.

Comment: @StianYttervik You do seem perfectly fluent. I only adjusted a bit of the phrasing to make the text flow better and ran it through a spell check, which accounted for most of the changes. :) I highly recommend installing a spell check plugin for your browser if you want to contribute regularly on SE.

Comment: And I mostly understood what you meant by those terms but hadn't heard of "step change" before, which seems to be a newer alternative for "paradigm shifts" and "quantum leaps". I mainly pointed it out because removing such jargon and replacing it with clear and simple phrases often greatly improves your writing. Consider as an example: "*means that your company may become too set in its ways to respond to changes or fail to follow evolutions in the market*"